# Filtering list using function values

Tags: warning-messages, filtering

I have a list (Basis) of size $2^{21}$, and a binary function $A$ defined on it (only outputs 0 or 1). I want to filter out the items from Basis that $A$ sends to 1. I was able to find the size of the filtered list via:

```
Apply[A, Basis, {1}];

Total[%];
```

> 8125;

But I need the actual 8,125 vectors. I've tried a few things, including:

```
Select[Basis, Apply[A, [#]] == 1 &]
```

But this, for example, gives me

> Syntax::sntxf: "Apply[A," cannot be followed by "[#]]".

What is the syntax issue, and is there a modification? If not, what would be an alternative approach?

Comment: You can use Pick: `Pick[Basis, A @@@ Basis, 1]`

Comment: you probably meant to use `Select[Basis, Apply[A, {#}] == 1 &]`?

Comment: @kglr that gives me an empty set. i didnt use it because the items in my list are arrays (vectors) so already have brackets around them. that was my logic anyway..

Comment: @CarlWoll Thank you, that works!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.